# Opening a STREAM in a Persistent Procedure Function

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I have a persistent procedure, in which I am trying to open, write and close a stream.

I have in the main area of the procedure

```
DEFINE STREAM sOutFile.
OPEN STREAM sOutFile TO VALUE( outFileName ).
MESSAGE SEEK( sOutFile ).
```

and subsequently a function within the persistent procedure

```
FUNCTION example RETURN LOGICAL:
  MESSAGE SEEK( sOutFile ).
  PUT STREAM sOutFile UNFORMATTED someData.
END.
```

When the persistent procedure is instantiated, the message displays "0" so the stream has been opened. However, when example is called, the message displays "?" and I get a message about attempting to write to a closed stream.

I've tried declaring the stream NEW SHARED but that didn't make any difference.

Am I doing something wrong, or is it impossible to define streams within persistent procedures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is early and my coffee hasn't kicked in yet but I think that you have to open the stream outside the body of the PP.

This works:

```
/* ppstream.p
 *
 */

define stream logStream.

session:add-super-procedure( this-procedure ).

/* end of PP init */

function initLog returns logical ( input lgFile as character ):
  output stream logStream to value( lgFile ) unbuffered.
  return true.
end.

function logStuff returns logical ( input msg as character ):
  put stream logStream unformatted msg skip.
  return true.
end.
```

and then call it like so:

```
function initLog  returns logical ( input lgFile as character ) in super.
function logStuff returns logical ( input msg as character ) in super.

run ./ppstream.p persistent.

initLog( "log.txt" ).
logStuff( "test" ).
```

(I used a session super-procedure to avoid having to define handles -- you would not necessarily need to do that.)

Comment: The initial call of a PP behaves just like a regular .p - any OUTPUT that's opened on the initial pass is closed when the procedure returns. This is why you need to open and close it this way - after the PP has been initially setup.