# Progress4gl - exporting to single csv file from multiple procedures?

Tags: csv, progress-4gl

In progress4gl, Iam exporting some values from mutiple procedure files to a single csv file. But when running the second procedure (.p) file the values which I got from the previous file is getting overwritten...How to export all datas of all the procedure files to a single csv file? Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Showing us some code will be helpful. If you are using OUTPUT TO statement, use APPEND

Comment: Thank you Austin..Its working:)

Comment: Sry I asked u wrongly.Actually what i want is, iam going to run the application only once.i.e, on clicking of a button (submit) it has to run the multiple .p files one by one.only the datas from those .p files has to get appended on that single csv file...if i run the app for second time it should be a new output .

Comment: For eg., i have 2 files 1.p & 2.p. In 1.p i have something like this - export stream {streamname} delimiter "," {somevalue}. The same code is in 2.p as well with someothervalue in the export. On clicking of submit button 1.p & 2.p are running one by one...but only the values of 2.p is present in the output csv file as values of 1.p is getting overwritted by this 2.p. please suggest me how to keep values of both files in that csv file.

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is to open the second and subsequent outputs to the file as

```
OUTPUT TO file.txt APPEND.
```

if that is all you need. If you are looking to do something more complex, then you could define and open a new shared stream in the calling program, and use that stream in each of the called programs, thus only opening and closing the stream once.

If you're using persistent procedures and functions, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31289078/opening-a-stream-in-a-persistent-procedure-function) may help, as it's a little more complex than normal shared streams.

Comment: Sry I asked u wrongly.Actually what i want is, iam going to run the application only once.i.e, on clicking of a button (submit) it has to run the multiple .p files one by one.only the datas from those .p files has to get appended on that single csv file...if i run the app for second time it should be a new output .

Answer (score 0):

I would realy not suggest to use a SHARED Stream. Especially with persischen Procedures or OO. STREAM-HANDLES provide a more flexible way of distributing the Stream.

Comment: For eg., i have 2 files 1.p & 2.p.  In 1.p i have something like this - export stream {streamname} delimiter "," {somevalue}. The same code is in 2.p as well with someothervalue in the export. On clicking of submit button 1.p & 2.p are running one by one...but only the values of 2.p is present in the output csv file as values of 1.p is getting overwritted by this 2.p. please suggest me how to keep both stream values in that csv file.

Comment: Define variable h ad handle no-undo.

Comment: h = STREAM {streamname}:Handle.

Answer (score 0):

So as was previously suggested 
on the first job running you do:
OUTPUT TO file.txt.

on all the other jobs running after this you do:
OUTPUT TO file.txt APPEND.

Comment: For eg., i have 2 files 1.p & 2.p.  In 1.p i have something like this - export stream {streamname} delimiter "," {somevalue}. The same code is in 2.p as well with someothervalue in the export. On clicking of submit button 1.p & 2.p are running one by one...but only the values of 2.p is present in the output csv file as values of 1.p is getting overwritted by this 2.p. please suggest me how to keep both stream values in that csv file.

Comment: in 1.p you output in 2.p you output append